# Generating unique coordinates

Tags: python, list, debugging, random, coordinates

As part of my course work to create a minesweeper-like game, I have been trying to generate a list of 15 coordinates and then take the first 5 towards Bandits and 10 towards my Treasure Chests.

I have been trying to sort these as they will be placed upon a 8x8 grid containing unique coords for both my chests and bandits, I have the following code, however, when printing each list, my coordinates seem to be the exact same.

```
import random
List=[]
emptylist=[]
while (len(emptylist)<20):
    List.append([random.randint(1,8),random.randint(1,8)])
    while List ==[1,1]:
      List.remove([1,1])
      print ("origin removed")
    [emptylist.append(x) for x in List if x not in emptylist]

print("-------------------")
print("   BANDIT COORDS")
print("-------------------")
for x in range(0,5):
    #print(emptylist[x])
    Bandits=[]
    [Bandits.append(emptylist[x]) for v in emptylist if v not in Bandits]
    print(Bandits[x])

print("-------------------")
print("   CHEST COORDS")
print("-------------------")    
for y in range(6,16):
   # print(emptylist[y])
     Chests=[]
     [Chests.append(emptylist[y]) for v in emptylist if v not in Chests]
     print(Chests[y])
print()
# Used to check the complete list
#print(emptylist)
```

I have used printing to debug the coordinates while they will not appear in the real game.

Comment: So you want to sort the Bandits? By which criteria?

Comment: I ran it on my system and got unique coordinates. Could you show us your output ?

Comment: I was told to add 2 dimensional lists which I forgot to include I had the following: coords = [Bandits, Chests] and then print(coords[0][1])